# Why don't my struct and array work?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have this `struct` and functions in my config.h :

```
typedef struct {
char *key;
char *value;
} configParam;

void loadSettings(char fileName[], struct configParam *paramsReaded[], int *length, int *statusCode){ 
   int i;
   for(i=0; i< *length; i++){

          //I try with strcpy(paramsReaded[i]->key,"key_from_txt"); and neither work :/
    strcpy(paramsReaded[i].key,"key_from_txt");   // HERE DONT WORK
    strcpy(paramsReaded[i].value,"value_from_txt");  // HERE DONT WORK

   }
}

void initialization(configParam *paramsReaded){
  paramsReaded->key = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
  paramsReaded->value = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
}
```

and in the main.c the call to functions and the variables:

```
int main()
{   //here parameters for loadsettings and the array type "configParam"
    configParam *parametersReaded[];
    inicializacion(&parametersReaded);
    char ruta[] = "config.txt";
    int length = 5;
    int statusCodeee;

   loadSettings(ruta,&parametersReaded,&length,&statusCodeee);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried in various ways for `strcpy`, but now I think there may be a problem in the main.c in initialization call. Any ideas?

Comment: You did not allocate (`malloc` or `calloc`) space for the pointer array: `configParam *parametersReaded[]` I would suggest something like `configParam **parametersReaded = calloc (10, sizeof *parametersReaded);` (or how ever many you need)

Comment: An error nobody has mentioned yet is that `struct configParam` should be `configParam`   (or, alternatively, the struct should be defined as `struct configParam {`)

Comment: That's because nobody tried to compile it and found a big **error:** staring at them `:p`

Comment: I doubt the code shown compiles. Is that the problem?

Comment: You should not put functions into a header file. This is the road to hell! Instead you put the _declaration_ (with 'extern' qualifier) into the header and the _definition_ into a `.c` file (implementation file).

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue you were having is you were not allocating space for the `struct` itself and then were not allocating enough memory for `key` and `value`.

Additionally **Always check to see if your allocation succeeded**. Otherwise you risk Undefined Behavior writing to memory not allocated to your struct.

Lastly, when you allocate memory, you are responsible for keeping track of it and freeing it when you are done. Here is a short example with your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* provide some minimum size that will hold keys & values */
#define MAXS 32

typedef struct {
    char *key;
    char *value;
} configParam;

void loadSettings(char *fileName, configParam *paramsReaded, int *length, int *statusCode)
{ 
    strcpy (paramsReaded->key,"key_from_txt");     /* or just use strdup and do away */
    strcpy (paramsReaded->value,"value_from_txt"); /* with your initialization       */
}

void initialization(configParam *paramsReaded)
{
    paramsReaded->key = malloc (MAXS * sizeof (char));
    paramsReaded->value = malloc (MAXS * sizeof (char));

    /* always check your allocation succeeded */
    if (!paramsReaded->key || !paramsReaded->value) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main()
{   
    configParam *parametersReaded = malloc (sizeof *parametersReaded); /* allocate at least 1 */

    /* always check your allocation succeeded */
    if (!parametersReaded) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    initialization (parametersReaded);

    char ruta[] = "config.txt";
    int length = 5;
    int statusCodeee = 0;

    loadSettings (ruta, parametersReaded,&length,&statusCodeee);

    // getchar();
    printf ("\n key  : %s\n value: %s\n\n", parametersReaded->key, parametersReaded->value);

    /* free allocated memory (note: checks are not required
       if you insure your pointers have not been freed earlier
       in your code.)  A simple free (pointer) will suffice. */
    if (parametersReaded->key) free (parametersReaded->key);
    if (parametersReaded->value) free (parametersReaded->value);
    if (parametersReaded) free (parametersReaded);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/initstruct

 key  : key_from_txt
 value: value_from_txt
```

**Note:** do not **cast** the result of `malloc`. It just invites hard to find errors. `paramsReaded->key = malloc (MAXS * sizeof (char));` is sufficient.

**Check for Memory Leaks/Errors**

If you are just beginning to allocate memory dynamically, make sure you confirm your memory use with a memory checker such as `valgrind` or similar tool on windows. They are simple to use, simply run your code through them. They will confirm your memory reads and writes do not involve errors (writing beyond your allocated space) and confirm that you have adequately freed all memory you allocated:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/initstruct
==6475== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6475== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6475== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6475== Command: ./bin/initstruct
==6475==

 key  : key_from_txt
 value: value_from_txt

==6475==
==6475== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6475==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6475==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 80 bytes allocated
==6475==
==6475== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6475==
==6475== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6475== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Comment: Are the last three `if`s required? becuase If any `malloc` fails, then the program will exit via the `exit` or `return`. BTW, you don't free `parametersReaded` if any of the other `malloc`s fail

Comment: No they are not, but I always try to impress that a check to insure that your pointers have not already been freed somewhere else in your code is a good idea to prevent segfault for double-free or memory corruption. But your point is 100% correct, they are not.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
 paramsReaded->key = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

you are allocating one byte of memory and this will not be enough to contain your whole string:

```
 strcpy(paramsReaded[i].key,"key_from_txt");
```

instead allocate enough bytes which is number of characters + 1 to hold the ending 0

```
 paramsReaded->key = (char *)malloc(strlen("key_from_txt")+1);
```

note also that you seem to want to have an array of structs so you need to repeat the above for each struct.

```
for(i=0; i< *length; i++)
{
   strcpy(paramsReaded[i].key = strdup(yourkey);
   strcpy(paramsReaded[i].value = strdup(yourvalue);
}
```

where yourkey and yourvalue is whatever texts you want to copy (strdup is the same as malloc + strcpy)

Comment: if you 're right , I was wrong to translate my code sorry, I have this in original code and that work but the strcpy no :(
------------------
paramsReaded->key = (char *)malloc(SIZE_MAX*sizeof(char));

Answer (score 1):

one more thing i noticed apart from ***CyberSpock***'s answer is

`configParam *parametersReaded[];`

You need to give number of array elements if you are not initializing them at the time of declaration(This is in general C concept).